# Applet does not show up in Blue J

Tags: java, applet, bluej

At school, I use Blue J on the school laptops. On those computers, the option to create an Applet appears when you click New Class. I recently downloaded Blue J on my home computer, and the option to create an Applet does not appear. I also copied in some code that imported Applet, but the class did not become an Applet and the Run Applet option did not appear when I right clicked the class. What do I do?

Comment: Read [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/), and abandon applets. They aren't supported any more, and are effectively dead.

Comment: At a guess, you've got a newer version of Blue J that doesn't support Applets.  They are effectively dead and, honestly, your time would be better spent learning something newer and supported.

Comment: [Applet is dead now](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/)

Answer (score 1):

I won't discuss why applets should not be used (although I agree with that) because it's not in your control as to what your CS teacher chooses to assign. I ran into the exact same situation setting up Bluej for my son's high school CS class. I found that the one machine it did not work on had BlueJ 4.x installed (more recent), and by going back and installing BlueJ 3.x the "Run Applet" appeared. I suggest trying that rather than trying to troubleshoot a (hopefully soon to be nonexistent) problem on the latest 4.x version.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the previous versions of Bluej, and try it out. The latest versions of Bluej is not supporting Applet programs. Bluej 3.1.7 is the last version that supports Applet. Applet has been deprecated and many modern browsers have removed support for Applet. So Applet is no more available in Bluej